# Upload Android Application To Market Error

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play

I Have An Error When I Start To Upload My Update Of My Application (my new apk) and it tells me that there's an error and by the way i signed my app with eclipse here's the error

```
Upload failed Your APK cannot be analyzed using aapt. Error output: Failed to run         
aapt dump badging: ERROR: dump failed because assets could not be loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some errors with your signing process. Make sure that you `Export Signed Application Package` and use a proper keystore.